Confusion about angle of attack difference between wings in a slip
CFI applicant here. I am experiencing some confusion regarding angle of attack difference between wings in a sideslip. When discussing stability, the PHAK says that that the lowered wing will have a higher angle of attack in a sideslip due to the dihedral. However in a sideslip, if a stall were to occur, the higher wing would stall first and drop. This seems to be contradictory. Any help would be appreciated.

I see dihedral discussed on page 5-18 of the PHAK (FAA-H-8083-25C) but where is the reference to "the higher wing would stall first"?

Depending on the aircraft the fuselage creates significant disturbances to the airflow of the trailing wing. This can reduce the effective area of the wing. The aileron on the trailing wing is also deflected down for the side-slip, which can cause a premature stall on that side. If the trailing and higher wing starts dropping, then it's angle of attack increases even further due to the roll rate and then a full stall on that wing can develop.

Because of the increased sweeping angle of the top wing there is needed for more airspeed velocity for minimum stall speed.The top wing is now a straight wing with the lower minimum stall speed.
